# UIView to AFOpenFlowView Casting

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am implementing the AFOpenFlowView, but I'm stuck when I cast UIView into AFOpenFlowView, When I run the code, it crashes here

```
[(AFOpenFlowView *)self.view setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];
```

And it always give error -[UIView setImage:forIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance, I feel it is not casting the UIView into AFOpenFlowView, any suggestion?

Comment: This means that setImage function is a  delgate method selector for UIImage and you are triggering this action for an UIView and thats why you get an error like this.

Comment: can you please elaborate it.